# What do the operators '<<' and '>>' do?

Tags: operators, go

I was following 'A tour of GO` on http://tour.golang.org.
The table 15 has some code that I cannot understand. It defines two constants with the following syntax:

```
const (
    Big = 1<<100
    Small = Big>>99
)
```

And it's not clear at all to me what it means. I tried to modify the code and run it with different values, to record the change, but I was not able to understand what is going on there.

Then, it uses that operator again on table 24. It defines a variable with the following syntax:

`MaxInt uint64 = 1<<64 - 1`

And when it prints the variable, it prints:

`uint64(18446744073709551615)`

Where `uint64` is the type. But I can't understand where `18446744073709551615` comes from.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift

Comment: 2^64 - 1 = 18446744073709551615

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are [Go's bitwise shift operators](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Arithmetic_operators).

[Here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/bitwise_operators.html)'s a good explanation of how they work for C (they work in the same way in several languages).
Basically `1<<64 - 1` corresponds to 2^64 -1, = 18446744073709551615.

Think of it this way. In decimal if you start from 001 (which is 10^0) and then shift the 1 to the left, you end up with 010, which is 10^1. If you shift it again you end with 100, which is 10^2. So shifting to the left is equivalent to multiplying by 10 as many times as the times you shift.

In binary it's the same thing, but in base 2, so 1<<64 means multiplying by 2 64 times (i.e. 2 ^ 64).

Answer (score 7):

That's the same as in all languages of the C family : a bit shift.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Bit_shifts

This operation is commonly used to multiply or divide an unsigned integer by powers of 2 :

```
b := a >> 1 // divides by 2
```

`1<<100` is simply `2^100` (that's Big).

`1<<64-1` is 2⁶⁴-1, and that's the biggest integer you can represent in 64 bits (by the way you can't represent `1<<64` as a 64 bits int and the point of table 15 is to demonstrate that you can have it in numerical constants anyway in Go).

Answer (score 1):

It's a [logical shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_shift):

> every bit in the operand is simply moved a given number of bit
>   positions, and the vacant bit-positions are filled in, usually with
>   zeros

[Go Operators](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Operators):

```
<<   left shift             integer << unsigned integer
>>   right shift            integer >> unsigned integer
```

Answer (score 1):

The >> and << are logical shift operations. You can see more about those here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_shift

Also, you can check all the Go operators in their [webpage](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Operators)